# How to apply a double filter (horizontal + vertical) in a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In google spreadsheets I'm looking for a formula like `filter()` that can filter both vertically and horizontally.

e.g. I can filter vertically

```
=filter(D4:H8, D3:H3=5)
```

or horizontally

```
=filter(D4:H8,C4:C8=2)
```

But I wonder if it's possible to do both at the same time.

I tried to put one into the other, but the problem is the second argument of the first filter, the dimension is unknown + I don't know how to reference column or row names.

I also tried the third argument of the `filter()` function but I get an error

```
=filter(D4:H8, D3:H3=5,C4:C8=2)
```

> Error
>   FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 5. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

Here is concrete example (with edit permissions) : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SYJuv2PQh72L-dfoH0xtugehe0EKp7ZNWHg_xbbqOBA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double Filter:

```
=filter(filter(D4:H8, D3:H3=5),C4:C8=2)
```